# Full screen under JavaFX with FXML

Tags: javafx, javafx-2

I have already asked the question but it was not answered.

How can I switch to full screen mode in JavaFX by pressing a button? 
But the button is created with FXML (JavaFX Scene Builder). (cannot find symbol (stage) )
If the button is created manually, then it works.

```
public class Buch extends Application implements Initializable
{

@ Override
    public void start (Stage primaryStage) throws IOException
    {

        Stage stage = primaryStage;

        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load (getClass () getResource ("Buch.fxml").);

        Scene scene = new Scene (root);

        stage.setTitle ("Buch");
        stage.setScene (scene);
        stage.getIcons () add (new Image ("Icon.png"));
        / / stage.setFullScreen (true) / / Works
        stage.show ();



    }

    @ FXML
    public void fullscreen (ActionEvent event)
    {

        / / stage.setFullScreen (true) / / Does not work
        / / cannot find symbol (stage)

    }
```

Works:

```
public class Buch extends Application implements Initializable
{

@ Override
    public void start (Stage primaryStage) throws IOException
    {

        Stage stage = primaryStage;

        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load (getClass () getResource ("Buch.fxml").);

        Scene scene = new Scene (root);

        stage.setTitle ("Buch");
        stage.setScene (scene);
        stage.getIcons () add (new Image ("Icon.png"));
        stage.show ();

        btn.setOnAction (new EventHandler <ActionEvent> ()
        {
            public void handle (ActionEvent evt)
            {
                stage.setFullScreen (true);
            }

        });

    }
```

Does not work (of course ?):

```
public class Buch extends Application implements Initializable
{

@ Override
    public void start (Stage primaryStage) throws IOException
    {

        Stage stage = primaryStage;

        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load (getClass () getResource ("Buch.fxml").);

        Scene scene = new Scene (root);

        stage.setTitle ("Buch");
        stage.setScene (scene);
        stage.getIcons () add (new Image ("Icon.png"));
        stage.show ();

* /
       @ FXML
    public void fullscreen (ActionEvent event)
    {

        stage.setFullScreen (true) / / Does not work
        / / cannot find symbol (stage)

    }
/ * / / Will not work


    }
```

You can also take a look at this link. The question is more detailed here:

stackoverflow.com/questions/22820049/full-screen-under-javafx-with-fxml-does-not-work

How can I use the stage variable anywhere? Or is there another solution ? 
Please help me.

On the internet there is NO answer to my question!?!

I am a Java beginner. :-)

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why is your Application also your controller? That seems like it won't work, full screen functionality or no full screen functionality.

In the ***controller***, just inject the button (or any node, but the button would be the obvious one), and call `getScene()` and `getWindow()` in the event handler:

```
public class MyController {
    @FXML
    private Button fullScreenButton ;

    @FXML
    private void fullScreen(ActionEvent event) {
       Stage stage = (Stage) fullScreenButton.getScene().getWindow();
       stage.setFullScreen(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: And very special thanks to James_D. 
This was the correct solution: 

Stage stage = (Stage) fullScreenButton.getScene () getWindow ().; 

You also have earned a "Vote Up" point, but I need 15 reputation points to do it :-(. I'll also do it if I have 15 points. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a JavaFX Expert, but this won't work in pure Java too.
The DI Container injects the method fullscreen(event) which doesn't know stage, declared in start().

Did u try to move it up to a class member ? 
    public class Buch
    {
    private Stage stage;
    ...
    }

Comment: It still wouldn't work, because the FXMLLoader used in the start() method creates a new instance, injects values into that new instance, and calls methods on it.

Comment: Thanks to HorstBrack for the answer. You were the first person who has answered to my question. Actually, you also have earned a "Vote Up" point, but I need 15 reputation points to do it :-(? I'll do it if I have 15 points. :-) 
I promise :-).